# Is there a name for the figure of speech where parts of a name are replaced with similar words for critical or comic effect?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

I'm struggling to explain it, but some examples are (mention does not imply endorsement!):

- Sir Keir Starmer -> Sir Kid Starver (criticism of his stance on child benefits)
- Benedict Cumberbatch -> Butterscotch Candybatch (surreal humour)
- Financial Conduct Authority -> Fundamentally Complicit Authority (critical of regulatory capture)
- Saddam Hussein -> Sadman Insane (general derision)

These are nicknames, i suppose, but they are a specific kind of nickname.

Comment: They are, first of all, *puns*.

Comment: I suggest there is not, simply because if there were, the topic would be irresistible to so many teachers of English, most of us would recognise it…

Answer (score -1):

It is a **malapropism**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/malapropism) has

> **malapropism**
>
> the wrong use of one word instead of another word because they sound similar to each other, with results that are unintentionally funny

It is also a **caricature**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/caricature) has

> **caricature**
>
> (the art of making) a drawing or written or spoken description of someone that usually makes them look silly by making part of their appearance or character more noticeable than it really is
>
> *Charles Dickens caricatured lawyers (= represented them in a way that made them look silly) in several of his novels.*

---

So you could say they are **malapropic caricatures**.

Comment: They're not malapropisms. Those are accidental. The word *unintentionally* there is the key one. They may be caricature(s), but they also may not be.

Comment: @Araucaria [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism) says "either unintentionally or for comedic effect".

Comment: If must be true then!  ;)

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malapropism) says "usually unintentional".

Comment: When they're intentional, it's usually as part of a comedy act where they're supposed to seem accidental. There have been a number of comedians who specialize in this type of humor (the most famous was Norm Crosby).